# FastCGI library for C#/Mono

Tags: mono, fastcgi

I'd like to write a couple of fastcgi applications in c#.

I know that Mono can run ASP.NET on fastcgi enabled web servers, but that is not what I need.

Is there any FastCGI library working for .NET/Mono?

Comment: This is definitely a question that belongs on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com); it's a programming question that involves a Linux compiler/environment

Comment: I do not agree since this Q&A site is targeted to "advanced" users. Most Unix / Linux advanced users are programmers.

Comment: What did you end up using by now?

Answer (score 4):

Its not fully functional/released yet but I am working on something that might interest you:

http://github.com/jacksonh/mango/blob/master/docs/tutorial/page-1.md

Comment: I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like a servlet interface?

You could also pretty easily emulate something like this using an ASPX HTTP Handler.  You simply inherit from IHttpAsyncHandler and you'll get a BeginProcessRequest method and an EndProcessRequest method.

In your BeginRequest handler you can do context.Response.Write ();

Comment: This is exactly what I mean but I'd prefer to avoid completely avoid ASP.NET
I'd like to write a "plain old FastCGI", but with C#.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a little bit too late to be usefull for you. Maybe it will be usefull to others.
Anyway I developed a fastcgi protocol implementation for .NET/mono. You can find it on github here: https://github.com/gigi81/sharpfastcgi

Comment: No, I'm still interessed. Looks very interesting @gigi ... what's the license?

Comment: Great! The license is BSD.